# A word to describe accomplishing some task while also maintaining that level of success

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or term that describes succeeding at a task while also maintaining that success across time.

An example without such a word or term:

- I'd like to congratulate the team for *successfully lowering* the incident rate *and maintaining the low rate* of incidents over the last few weeks.

I'm looking for a more concise way of expressing the same thing.

Maybe something like the following?

- I'd like to congratulate the team for *effectively?* lowering the incident rate over the last few weeks.

Is there a better way to express such a sentiment?

Comment: I can understand that you might congratulate someone on ***maintaining the lead** and [thereby] **winning** the race*, but it doesn't really make sense to me to ***reverse*** those two "achievements".

Comment: I'd like to congratulate the team for being "successful over time".

Comment: Their *continued success* at [stuff].

Answer (score 1):

> "I'd like to congratulate the team for ***consistently*** lowering the
> incident rate over the last few weeks."

M-W:

> **[consistent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consistent)**
> *adjective*
>
> : **always acting** or behaving **in the same way**
>
> : **of the same quality**; especially : **good each time**
>
> : **continuing to happen** or develop **in the same way**
>
> - **consistently**  *adverb*
>
> Customers expect that the quality of service they receive will be
> consistent.
>
> Your grades have shown consistent improvement this school year.

Comment: This lacks the aspect of "maintaining". Rather, it keeps on consistently changing constantly.

Comment: Check the second definition of _same quality_. I believe it fits your _mainitaing_ requirement.

Comment: consistently *low* incident rate; no *ing*. Which means, no *ly* on "consistent", either. Or does it? Should you ever say "consistently low" ? Sounds right to me...

Answer (score 1):

The OP's sentence:

> I'd like to congratulate the team for successfully lowering the
>   incident rate and maintaining the low rate of incidents over the last
>   few weeks.

Possible rewording:

> I'd like to congratulate the team for its *vigilance* in continuing
>   to lower the incident rate over the last few weeks.

*Vigilance* is a good *safety* word. From Dictionary.com:

> *vigilance*: keenly watchful to detect danger; wary

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to congratulate the team for **sustaining** a low (or lower or lowered) incident rate
>   over the last few weeks.

The relevant meaning, from the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sustain) website is:

> cause to continue or be prolonged for an extended period or without
>   interruption.

Answer (score 0):

achieve *lasting* success

lasting: *enduring or able to endure over a long period of time.
"they left a lasting impression"*

Your example:

> I'd like to congratulate the team for their **lasting success** in lowering the incident rate.